# Enviromental variables not working in next.js

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to use enviromental variables to store secret key for nextauth.
I store it in .env.local in root folder.
Format of the variable is NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET=secretkey
I know that program works because when i swap process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET for plain string if works and doesn't show errors. But when i try to use env variable it shows me error "no secret key".
I also tried to add NEXTAUTH_ before SECRET instead of NEXT_PUBLIC
I'm working in visual studio code in case that matters.

EDIT:
I found workaround for secret key. Added NEXTAUTH_SECRET to .env.local and now i don't have to add secret option into options.js. Still doesn't solve my problem for google and github keys and ids.